# Combining columns into single columns with a bridge

Tags: mysql, database

I am working with a mysql database but I am facing a problem. I have a list of users which looks something like this.

```
   Users
+----+------+
| ID | Name | 
+----+------+
|  1 | Jim  |
|  2 | Cal  |
|  3 | Rob  |
|  4 | John |
|  5 | Paul |
+----+------+
```

Now I have two more tables,

```
   Teams           Role
+----+----------+   +---+------+
| ID | NameTeam |   |ID | Role |
+----+----------+   +---+------+
|  1 | Team1    |   | 1 |Leader|
|  2 | Team2    |   | 2 |Member|
|  3 | Team3    |   | 3 |Role3 |
|  4 | Team4    |   | 4 |Role4 |
|  5 | Team5    |   | 5 |Role5 |
+----+----------+   +---+------+
```

Please not that all IDs are primary keys.

Finally there is a table that serves as a bridge for the tables above.

```
           Bridge
+---------+--------+--------+
| ID_team | ID_user| ID_role|
+---------+--------+--------+
|  1      | 1      | 1      |
|  1      | 2      | 2      |
|  1      | 3      | 3      |
|  2      | 4      | 1      |
|  2      | 5      | 2      |
|  2      | 1      | 3      |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

All these three columns are foreign keys that are linked to the primary keys in the three tables Users,Teams and Role.

What I would like is a list of all users and in one column the information of the teams they are part of, along with the role they have in that team. I figured I could do this by a left join but it is possible for a user to be linked to multiple teams and then the row will duplicate.

My query so far:

```
select * from Users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bridge
ON Bridge.UserID = Users.UserID;
```

Which results in duplicates like:

```
    Result 
+----+------+---------+--------+--------+
| ID | Name | ID_team | ID_user| ID_role|
+----+------+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Jim  |  1      | 1      | 1      | << Twice Jim here
|  1 | Jim  |  2      | 1      | 3      | <<
|  2 | Cal  |  1      | 2      | 2      |
|  3 | Rob  |  1      | 3      | 3      |
|  4 | John |  2      | 4      | 1      |
|  5 | Paul |  2      | 5      | 2      |
+----+------+---------+--------+--------+


    Desired result
+----+------+----------------------------+
| ID | Name | Team and role              |
+----+------+----------------------------+
|  1 | Jim  |  Team1: Leader,Team2:role3 | <<Nice sum up.
|  2 | Cal  |  Team1: Member             |
|  3 | Rob  |  Team1: Role3              |
|  4 | John |  Team2: Leader             |
|  5 | Paul |  Team2: Member             |
+----+------+----------------------------+
```

Is something like this even possible with a single query? If not I could always create something similar by using php but it would be really nice if it could be a single query.

So my question is, how can I get the desired result?

Comment: Surely you bridge table needs splitting into 2 bridge tables 1) User is in Team and 2) User has role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join all the tables first.

Then for your desired output you need to use `CONCAT` along with `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT 
U.ID,
U.Name,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(T.NameTeam,':',R.Role)) AS 'Team and Role'
FROM Bridge B
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.ID = B.ID_user 
INNER JOIN Teams T ON T.ID = B.ID_team 
INNER JOIN Role R ON R.ID = B.ID_role
GROUP BY B.ID_user
```

---

**EDIT:**

In order to get result for all users irrespective of whether the corresponding record exists in `Bridge` table or not:

```
SELECT 
U.ID,
U.Name,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(T.NameTeam,':',R.Role)) AS 'Team and Role'
FROM Users U 
LEFT JOIN Bridge B ON U.ID = B.ID_user 
LEFT JOIN Teams T ON T.ID = B.ID_team 
LEFT JOIN Role R ON R.ID = B.ID_role
GROUP BY U.ID;
```

---

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e2fb2/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. There is only one small thing which I see I might forgot to mention. If the user is not part of a team, it should still be listed. I tried to use your answer with different kinds of Joins but that didn't seem to work. Is this also possible? The rest of the table came out perfect!

Comment: You need to change the order as well as switch from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. Please check the updated answer under **edit** section. @Daan

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!